# Notification on InvalidateVisual

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF the ArrangeOverride is called whan InvalidateVisual / InvalidateArrange is called on the UIElement. This in most cases is caused by a change in a DP which has the AffectsRender / AffectsArrange flag set, but in advanced cases this can be called explicitly as well. Now is there a way to determine when is the InvalidateVisual explicitly called on a specific UIElement? Or more specifically is there a way to determine what exactly caused the ArrangeOverride to be called on an element?

Comment: It would be helpful, if you would post your code. Also please take a minute and read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, it's not unless you keep track of this information yourself in a custom control.